# Expand row in a table with Two Dimensional Scrollable

Tags: flutter, mobile, tableview

I am currently using Flutter Two Dimensional Scrollable package and I need to build an expand row feature. When I click the row, I need the row to expand and reveal an expanded row (like a dropdown button) with extra content.

I implemented some sort of expand row feature, but I have made it by a very simple and inelegant way. Basically, I doubled the row height and building the expanded content strictly below de primary content. I wonder if Two Dimensional Scrollable package has a native way to do this implementation.

Comment: share something more, like demo. to ans your question u can use AnimatedContainer( height: _isSelected ? 140:50 , width: _isSelected ? 200: 50 ).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.